# Express.js request params undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've got the following node/express code:

```
app.get("/notes/:categoryName", function (res, req) {
    var categoryName = req.params.categoryName;
    res.render("notes", {title: categoryName});
});
```

But when I look at req.params, it's undefined.

Yet, in another controller it works fine:

```
app.get("/api/notes/:categoryName", function (req, res) {
    var categoryName = req.params.categoryName;

    data.getNotes(categoryName, function (err, notes) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(400, err);
        } else {
            res.set("Content-Type", "application/json");
            res.send(notes.notes);
        }
    });
});
```

What's the deal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
app.get("/notes/:categoryName", function (res, req) {
```

More attention :

```
app.get("/notes/:categoryName", function (req, res) {
```

You switched the params (res, req)

Comment: Thanks, that was definitely a "D'oh!" moment for me.

Comment: Hi , 
Suppose "/mobile/custom/******/deviceVersion/:deviceType" is my request .
could you please tell me how to check "deviceType" against undefined?

Comment: Hi , 
Suppose "/mobile/custom/******/deviceVersion/:deviceType" is my request .
could you please tell me how to check "deviceType" against undefined?